Monoidality of Strict Free Cocompletion
For a small category $\mathcal{C}$, the free cocompletion is given by the category $\mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ of presheaves $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$. Alternatively, it can be described as the following category $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$:

Objects are small diagrams in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. functors $F: \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ with $\mathcal{I}$ small
As morphisms between diagrams $F: \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}, G: \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$, we set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\hat{\mathcal{C}}}(F, G) = \lim_i \mathrm{colim}_j \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(i), G(j))$
Composition is inherited from $\mathcal{C}$.

If $Y: \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ is the Yoneda embedding, then $L: \hat{\mathcal{C}} \to \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C}), F \mapsto \mathrm{colim}_i Y(F(i))$ is an equivalence of categories. This the construction of the strict free cocompletion due to Beurier-Pastor-Guitart.
Q1: Is my understanding of this construction correct?
Now suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is (strict) monoidal. Then $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is monoidal by defining the monoidal product of diagrams $F: \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}, G: \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}$ to be $\mathcal{I} \times \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$. Also, $\mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ is monoidal with respect to the Day convolution $\otimes_D$. The Yoneda embedding $Y: \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ is canonically monoidal and $- \otimes_D -$ is cocontinuous in both variables.
Q2: Is $L$ an equivalence of monoidal categories? Are there references for such a construction?
In the end, I would like everything to be $\mathrm{Vec}$-enriched, i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ is $k$-linear monoidal, and we replace $\mathrm{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ by the $\mathrm{Vec}$-enriched presheaves $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathrm{Vec}$. The limits and colimits in the above lim-colim-formula are taken in $\mathrm{Vec}$.
Q3: Are there references in the enriched setting?

Do you know about weighted colimits? Are you aware that, in general, you need weighted colimits and not just conical colimits? (As it happens, for vector spaces over a field, things simplify. But I do not think you will find references that work at that level of specificity.)

Indeed, I was hoping that moving from $\mathrm{Set}$-enrichment $\mathrm{Vec}$-enrichment wouldn't change too much. But I'd already be happy for references working over $\mathrm{Set}$.
